# Towers of Hanoi Closed Form Solution

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, towers-of-hanoi

So I'm trying to find the closed form solution for the Towers of Hanoi problem.  I understand that the recurrence relation is T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1, because it takes T(n-1) to move the top of the tower back and forth which is why there are two, and the "+ 1" is to move the base.  However, I cannot understand why the closed solution is 2^n - 1.

When I am trying to solve for the answer and I use back substitution, I get as far as: T(n) = 8T(n-3) + 4 + 2 + 1, which is T(n) = 2^k (T(n - k)) + 2^k-1 + 2^k-2 + 2^k-3 where k is the step?  I know the last part is also geometric series, which means it is 2^(n + 1) - 1/(2-1).  But I just can't understand where the answer comes from.

edit:
is it because the geometric series part is not 2^k + 2^k-1 + ... + 2^k-k? which means that the geometric series is not 2^n + 1 - 1, but rather 2^n - 1. and we use H(0) as the base case --> so H(n - k), use k = n?

Comment: Re "But I just can't understand where the answer comes from." [You *guess*.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OL6-x0modwY)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily prove it by induction. Let's assume that `T(n) = 2^n - 1` is true for a given `n`. Then:

```
T(n+1) = 2*T(n) + 1
       = 2*(2^n-1) + 1
       = 2^(n+1) - 2 + 1
       = 2^(n+1) - 1
```

As we know that `T(0) = 0 = 2^0 - 1` it proves that for any `n` the equality `T(n) = 2^n - 1` is true.

Answer (score 0):

A trick which *sometimes* works is to find another function for which the relation is simpler.

So we start from `T(n)=2*T(n-1)+1`.

It looks similar to `T(n)=2*T(n-1)` which has an obvious solution.

So we should transform the equation so that `+1` is inside of `2*(...)`.

In this case it's `T(n)+1=2*T(n-1)+2=2*(T(n-1)+1)`.

So `T(n)+1=2^n*(T(0)+1)` and `T(n)=2^n*(T(0)+1)-1`.